# How can I count the result of an ActiveRecord .group query? Chaining .count returns a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can use the following :

```
User.where("zip_code = '48104'").group('users.id').count
```

To get hashes like :

```
{195=>1, 106=>1, 120=>1, 227=>1, 247=>1, 264=>1, 410=>1}
```

Is there a way I can count these hashes, and just return **7**, instead of the above result ?

I know this doesn't make sense in the above scenario, and I can just do it by not using the **group** clause. But I'm working on a more complex query, where I need to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get the length of *any* hash with `.length`

Comment: @meagar: However, that requires returning all the records as objects and then counting them up. It's a bit of a performance hog.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
User.where("zip_code = '48104'").group('users.id').count.length
```

Comment: any way to do this without pulling all the records from the db?

Comment: You can do it with a subselect in raw SQL. You'll need to use the raw database connection in order to do that: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection

Comment: It's hackish, but another way to reduce the amount pulled from the database is to throw in a .select('id') scope, to avoid summoning the other columns.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is not scalable.  Using @robbrit's method on a query with 25,000 matching users would pull 25,000 results (ie an array with 25,000 elements) into memory and then count the elements array.  Here is a method that will do it without pulling all that data:

```
def count_query(query)
  query = "SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM (#{query.to_sql}) x"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).first.try(:[], 0).to_i
end
```

It is used like this:

```
query = User.where("zip_code = '48104'").group('users.id')
count = count_query(query)
```

This works for me using mysql, btw.

It was inspired by this guy: https://github.com/mrbrdo/active_record_group_count/blob/master/lib/active_record_group_count/scope.rb

Answer (score 5):

As said before by *orourkedd* the accepted answer is not great when dealing with a large amount of records. I too recently encountered this issue and have large tables that I definitely don't want to load into memory. So here is what works for me.

```
users=User.where("zip_code = '48104'").group('users.id')
user_count=User.where(id: users.select(:id)).count
```

Rails will handle the users.select part like a subquery. This works with **Rails 4**

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the values of the hashes together then:

```
{key1: 1, key2: 2}.values.inject(:+) # => 3
```

If you just want the number of keys then:

```
{key1: 1, key2: 2}.length # => 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the first count() is returning a hash, use whatever Ruby enumerable operations you wish on it.  Example:

```
User.where("zip_code = '48104'").group('users.id').count.count
```

See also:

- http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000292
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count

Comment: Very nice explanation of what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, useful if the values can be > 1.

```
User.where("zip_code = '48104'").group('users.id').count.values.sum
```