# How do I write a scope for an association that has a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this:

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :shirts,
        join_table: "attendances_shirts",
        association_foreign_key: "shirt_id", foreign_key: "attendance_id"

        # I'd like to be able to write this scope, specifying
        # only the attendances that have shirt records
        scope :with_shirts, ??????

end
```

I've some examples with join, and where, but I haven't found them to be very straight forward.

Again, I'd like help select attendances where an attendance has at least one shirt record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this without join. Scope is to return association object and hence all the 'calculations' needs to be performed inside db. The only way db is able to figure out which attendance has shirts is to perform join.

```
scope :with_shirts, select("#{table_name}.*").joins(:shirts).group(:id)
```

UPDATE:

To handle count returning hashes, you could probably do:

```
scope :with_shirts, select("#{table_name}.*").joins(:shirts).group(:id).extending do
  def count
    super.length
  end
end
```

Comment: I changed the group to `group("shirts.id") to avoid ambiguous column names. But when I did `Attendances.with_shirts.count`, I got `{}` :-\  Why did that happen?

Comment: I did the same with an attendance that actually had shirts, and it gave me this after calling count `{1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1}` count should count the the number of AR objects being returned, yeah? (also, I changed the group by to be the "attendance_id", so I don't get duplicate attendances returned )

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283847/count-returned-hashes

Comment: what if, instead of the hash, I want the attendance records? (say, before I call count?)

Comment: neat. how do I use `.count`? to count the results of with_shirts? doing with_shirts.count returns a hash

Comment: Update answer. It's probably not the cleanest solution, but definitely work, any cleaner versions are most welcome.